# How to correctly use Builder Pattern with cucumber steps

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, builder

I am currently using Cucumber bdd scenarios to build and send requests and then ensure the response is okay.

I wanted to use the Builder pattern to build my requests but I am unsure if I am using it correctly.

Here is an example of my Search Class which uses lombok builder.

```
@Builder()
@Data
@Getter
public class Search {

    private Preferences preferences;
    private String pos;
    private String languageCode;
    @Singular("traveler")
    private List<Traveler> traveler;

}
```

and here is an example of a Preferences class that is part of the Search class.
Notice here I do not use lombok builder

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Setter
public class Preferences {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
   
}
```

Here is an example of my Step Definitions

```
public class SearchSteps {
    Preferences preferences = new Preferences();

    @Given("^user adds perferences")
    public void userAddsPerferences(String foo) throws Exception {
        preferences.setFoo(foo);

    }

    @Given("^user sends search$")
    public void user_sends_search(String bar) throws Exception {
        preferences.setBar(bar);
        Search search = Search.builder()
                .preferences(preferences)
                .languageCode("en")
                .pos("test")
                .build();
    }
```

So to explain a bit more. I know that when a user sends a Search object they will **always** need to add a Preference with a Bar string set.
I also know a user will sometimes want to add more preferences before a Search request is sent, so the userAddsPerferences step will be used in some tests but not all  (*Note: I only added two fields to Preferences to illustrate the issue*)

I originally added lombok builders to all object classes that Search makes use of but then I couldn't find a way of spreading the creation of the Preferences object across multiple steps.

Is okay to build smaller objects like this across steps (if needed), with chained setters and then build the main request Object with the builder pattern?

or am I overthinking the use of Builder pattern and is the neat chained setters all I making use of from the pattern?

Comment: I am not sure what you issue exactly is.. Are you asking about how to share Preferences among all possible steps in your Scenario?

Comment: So if use the lombok builder it will create immutable objects means I can't spread the creation of Preferences across steps, so I removed the builder from that class I'm just wondering if this is okay and should I only use a builder for the final search object?